# Trouble installing Ubuntu onto an older intel Pentium 4 machine

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, 32-bit

I am completely new to Linux and that is why I am trying to do is set up an older PC with a 32bit version of Ubuntu. This computer has an Intel 4 cpu 3.20GHz, DRAM 400MHz, 1024 MB RAM. The issue I am having is at the initial startup of the computer. I get a screen which displays the following:

```
Isolinux.bin missing or corrupt. 
Intel (R) Boot Agent FE v4.1.16

Intel (R) Boot Agent PXE Base Code (PXE-2.1 build 084)
Copyright (C) 1997-2004, Intel Corporation

PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
No Bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

I have tried making several copies of the Iso disk and different versions of Ubuntu...nothing has helped. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: did you installed ubuntu or trying to install it?

Comment: Looks like your computer is trying to boot from the network.  Make sure you disable PXE/network boot in the bios and set it to boot from the proper drive.

Comment: I am trying to install Ubuntu.

Comment: How do I set the bios to not boot from network?

Comment: Where are you booting from CD/DVD?  Does your system allow booting from USB? How was the installation media created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer is attempting to boot using Intel's network boot bios feature. You need to tell your computer to boot from your cd/dvd drive. Most computers have 2 bios menus setup and boot device list. The button you use to enter these varies from computer to computer, for me it is F12/F2.

Step 1: Turn on the computer

Step 2: Press f12 (you may need to press it a few times), to enter the boot device list

Step 3: insert the Ubuntu dvd or cd

Step 4: on the list choose your cd/dvd device as the device you wish to boot from
[Please note this is a 1 time boot, your default boot device settings will not be changed, if you don't know what this means then this IS what you want]

Step 5: The disc should now boot, if it doesn't then it means your cd or dvd isn't being detected, and therefore the boot process continues to the next device on your boot order. In which case you will need to confirm the disc is valid and consider other installation methods such as usb.

Comment: Thank you and I agree. I have tried making several disks using Nero but non, thus far have been recognized. I will try to use a USB stick instead.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the helpful advice! After coming home from work, using your advice allowed me to get Ubuntu going. I will be back with more questions shortly:)